# Iterate dictionary and remove / add keys inside game loop

Tags: c#

I am creating a console application game. 
The game contains `Point` object (`x` and `y` properties) and `GameObject` which other classes inherit from.

I create a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<Point, List<GameObject>> myDict
```

Each point in the dictionary stores list with object / objects. I don't wanna empty points. An example for initializing dictionary:

```
1. <(0,0), List<obj1>>
2. <(35,10), List<obj2, obj3>>
3. <(8,9), List<obj4, obj5>>
4. <(40,3), List<obj6>>
```

If `obj1` moves to (0,1):

```
<(0,1), List<obj1>>
<(35,10), List<obj2, obj3>>
<(8,9), List<obj4, obj5>>
<(40,3), List<obj6>>
```

As you can see, the pair with the `key` (0,0) has been removed and (0,1) has been added.

if `obj2` moves to (8,9):

```
<(0,1), List<obj1>>
<(35,10), List<obj3>>
<(8,9), List<obj4, obj5, obj2>>
<(40,3), List<obj6>>
```

In this case, `obj2` has just been removed from the list and the key wasn't removed because it stores `obj3` and it's not empty. `obj3` was added to (8,9) list.

These manipulations will be done every 250 milliseconds, inside the game loop, automatically. I tried to use `foreach loop`, something like that:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<Point, List<GameObject>> kvp in myDict)
{
        foreach (GameObject obj in kvp.Value) {
                obj.move();
        }
}
```

But it doesn't work because as I understood I cannot add / remove keys when I iterate.

Do you have any suggestions?

Some important thing:

- I have to use dictionary for that.
- `GameObject` don't have `Point` property. you can know where the
  `GameObject` located only if you check in the dictionary. please
  don't tell me to add this property because I can't and that not the
  target.

Comment: this solution seems best http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892790/deleting-while-iterating-over-a-dictionary

Comment: You can't change or remove the keys in the context of an enumerator but nothing prevents you from getting all `KeyValuePair` to an array and then manipulating that.. I know you said you _have_ to use a Dictionary, but it's not the right structure for what you want.

Comment: Your restriction on not adding the `Point` property to the `GameObject` seems very arbitrary. Is there any reason behind it?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to stick with a Dictionary, the easiest way to solve your problem would be to use a temporary Dictionary while you iterate, so you can actually remove/add keys.

As I understand from your foreach loop, every GameObject is going to move, so you could just iterate on your Dictionary and build a new one from scratch with the new values.

Answer (score 0):

Questionable design practices aside, this will probably fix your concurrent modifications issue:

```
foreach (GameObject obj in myDict.SelectMany(pair=>pair.Value).ToList())
{
    obj.move();
}
```